# Sending a HTTP request to Google Script in Arduino

Tags: http, arduino

I am using the following code which sends and receives a HTTP request to the custom website with no problem. However when I try to change the host to following I get a failure message. You can simply put this address into browser to see the actual response.

I need to change     const char* host = "djxmmx.net"; to     const char* host = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby72HRgl874tst5e0FBHDa_VR6luqofn-ojiYF8KUBPmC2E3aiB/exec";

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "Phone";
const char* password = "aa";

const char* host = "djxmmx.net";
const uint16_t port = 17;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi networkre

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  /* Explicitly set the ESP8266 to be a WiFi-client, otherwise, it by default,
     would try to act as both a client and an access-point and could cause
     network-issues with your other WiFi-devices on your WiFi-network. */
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.print(host);
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.println(port);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    delay(5000);
    return;
  }

  // This will send a string to the server
  Serial.println("sending data to server");
  client.println("hello from ESP8266");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      delay(60000);
      return;
    }
  }

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  Serial.println("receiving from remote server");
  while (client.available()) {
    char ch = static_cast<char>(client.read());
    Serial.print(ch);
  }

  // Close the connection
  //Serial.println();
  //Serial.println("closing connection");
 // client.stop();

  //delay(300000); // execute once every 5 minutes, don't flood remote service
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way using some help as mentioned. This requires a data server setup in Google app in this link [GoogleSheetScript](https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293). Note how "name=Amir" transfer your data.

```
    /*  HTTPS on ESP8266 with follow redirects, chunked encoding support
     *  Version 2.1
     *  Author: Sujay Phadke
     *  Github: @electronicsguy
     *  Copyright (C) 2017 Sujay Phadke <electronicsguy123@gmail.com>
     *  All rights reserved.
     *
     *  Example Arduino program
     */

    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include "HTTPSRedirect.h"
    #include "DebugMacros.h"

    // Fill ssid and password with your network credentials
    const char* ssid = "AmirPhone";
    const char* password = "aa112233";

    const char* host = "script.google.com";
    // Replace with your own script id to make server side changes
    const char *GScriptId = "AKfycby72HRgl874tst5e0FBHDa_VR6luqofn-ojiYF8KUBPmC2E3aiB";

    const int httpsPort = 443;

    // echo | openssl s_client -connect script.google.com:443 |& openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout
    const char* fingerprint = "";

    // Write to Google Spreadsheet
    String url = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?name=Amir";
    // Fetch Google Calendar events for 1 week ahead
    String url2 = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?cal";
    // Read from Google Spreadsheet
    String url3 = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?read";

    String payload_base =  "";
    String payload = "";

    HTTPSRedirect* client = nullptr;
    // used to store the values of free stack and heap
    // before the HTTPSRedirect object is instantiated
    // so that they can be written to Google sheets
    // upon instantiation
    unsigned int free_heap_before = 0;
    unsigned int free_stack_before = 0;

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.flush();

      //free_heap_before = ESP.getFreeHeap();
      //free_stack_before = cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont);
      Serial.printf("Free heap before: %u\n", free_heap_before);
      Serial.printf("unmodified stack   = %4d\n", free_stack_before);

      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Connecting to wifi: ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
      // flush() is needed to print the above (connecting...) message reliably, 
      // in case the wireless connection doesn't go through
      Serial.flush();

      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected");
      Serial.println("IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

      // Use HTTPSRedirect class to create a new TLS connection
      client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
      client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
      client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");

      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(host);

      // Try to connect for a maximum of 5 times
      bool flag = false;
      for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        int retval = client->connect(host, httpsPort);
        if (retval == 1) {
           flag = true;
           break;
        }
        else
          Serial.println("Connection failed. Retrying...");
      }

      if (!flag){
        Serial.print("Could not connect to server: ");
        Serial.println(host);
        Serial.println("Exiting...");
        return;
      }

      if (client->verify(fingerprint, host)) {
        Serial.println("Certificate match.");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Certificate mis-match");
      }

      // Send memory data to Google Sheets
      payload = payload_base + "\"" + free_heap_before + "," + free_stack_before + "\"}";
      client->POST(url2, host, payload, false);
      payload = payload_base;// + "\"" + ESP.getFreeHeap() + "," + cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont) + "\"}";
      client->POST(url2, host, payload, false);

      // Note: setup() must finish within approx. 1s, or the the watchdog timer
      // will reset the chip. Hence don't put too many requests in setup()
      // ref: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/34

      Serial.println("\nGET: Write into cell 'A1'");
      Serial.println("=========================");

      // fetch spreadsheet data
      client->GET(url, host);

      // Send memory data to Google Sheets
      payload = payload_base;// + "\"" + ESP.getFreeHeap() + "," + cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont) + "\"}";
      client->POST(url2, host, payload, false);

      Serial.println("\nGET: Fetch Google Calendar Data:");
      Serial.println("================================");

      // fetch spreadsheet data
      client->GET(url2, host);

      // Send memory data to Google Sheets
      payload = payload_base;// + "\"" + ESP.getFreeHeap() + "," + cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont) + "\"}";
      client->POST(url2, host, payload, false);

      Serial.println("\nSeries of GET and POST requests");
      Serial.println("===============================");

      Serial.printf("Free heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
      Serial.printf("unmodified stack   = %4d\n");//, cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont));

      // delete HTTPSRedirect object
      delete client;
      client = nullptr;
    }

    void loop() {
      static int error_count = 0;
      static int connect_count = 0;
      const unsigned int MAX_CONNECT = 20;
      static bool flag = false;
      //Serial.printf("Free heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
      //Serial.printf("unmodified stack   = %4d\n", cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont));

      if (!flag){
        //free_heap_before = ESP.getFreeHeap();
       // free_stack_before = cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont);
        client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
        flag = true;
        client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
        client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
      }

      if (client != nullptr){
        if (!client->connected()){
          client->connect(host, httpsPort);
          payload = payload_base + "\"" + free_heap_before + "," + free_stack_before + "\"}";
          client->POST(url2, host, payload, false);
        }
      }
      else{
        DPRINTLN("Error creating client object!");
        error_count = 5;
      }

      if (connect_count > MAX_CONNECT){
        //error_count = 5;
        connect_count = 0;
        flag = false;
        delete client;
        return;
      }

      Serial.println("GET Data from cell 'A1':");
      if (client->GET(url3, host)){
        ++connect_count;
      }
      else{
        ++error_count;
        DPRINT("Error-count while connecting: ");
        DPRINTLN(error_count);
      }

      Serial.println("POST append memory data to spreadsheet:");
      payload = payload_base;// + "\"" + ESP.getFreeHeap() + "," + cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont) + "\"}";
      if(client->POST(url2, host, payload)){
        ;
      }
      else{
        ++error_count;
        DPRINT("Error-count while connecting: ");
        DPRINTLN(error_count);
      }

      /*
      if (!(client.reConnectFinalEndpoint())){
        ++error_count;
        DPRINT("Error-count while connecting: ");
        DPRINTLN(error_count);
      }
      else
        error_count = 0;
      */

      if (error_count > 3){
        Serial.println("Halting processor..."); 
        delete client;
        client = nullptr;
        Serial.printf("Final free heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
        Serial.printf("Final unmodified stack   = %4d\n");//, cont_get_free_stack(&g_cont));
        Serial.flush();
        ESP.deepSleep(0);
      }

      // In my testing on a ESP-01, a delay of less than 1500 resulted 
      // in a crash and reboot after about 50 loop runs.
      delay(4000);

    }


  [1]: https://github.com/electronicsguy/ESP8266/blob/master/HTTPSRedirect/GoogleScript.gs
```

Comment: I tried above code sometime it connects with script.google.com and works fine but sometime it does not connects with script.google.com and returns code 0, while pinging  script.google.com from cmd works. any idea regrading same

Comment: I understand google has updated the script altogether. This code may need to be rewritten.